# Querying in Gremlin using multiple indices

Tags: neo4j, gremlin

I am trying to optimize requests in Gremlin on a Neo4J graph.

Here is the short version of the basic request I am using:

```
g.idx("myIndex")[[myId:5]].outE("HAS_PRODUCT").filter{it.shop_id:5}.inV
```

So I looked into indexation and got to create an index on `"HAS_PRODUCT"`-typed edges with key `'shop_id'`.

Using the same request, I don't see a big difference.

My questions are:

- Is my new index used when I query with: `filter{it.shop_id:5}`
- If not, how can I use this new index in my request?
- More generally, if `idx(` is the graph method to use an index, is there a pipe method for that?

Thanks!

Comment: I realized my answer didn't fully cover all of your questions.  To fully answer, I have a question of my own.  In this particular case, you know the ID of `shop_id` which is an edge index.  Since you know that value, wouldn't it be best to start your traversal from there, as you then know both the much more limited set of inV/outV (I'm assuming `myId:5` has a lot of edges)?

Comment: I actually shortened my query, but the main scheme is the one above, the full query has 2 filters and the total traversal is of about 5 edges. `myId:5` doesn't have much edges, it corresponds to a list of products. However, `g.idx("by_shopid")[[shop_id:5]]` has a lot of incoming `"HAS_PRODUCT"` relationships. If I want to get products in that shop that corresponds to products on that list, I need to traverse from the list to the shop (or the other way around). Starting from the shop with an indexed request on `shop_id` would produce the hole shop catalog, I'll still have to traverse to my list

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is that Gremlin won't make use of the secondary index when using Neo4j, but please consider reading the longer answer below in relation to TinkerPop, Gremlin and its philosophy.

The longer answer is....Indices are not being used for your `shop_id`.  When you call `outE` you are effectively iterating all the edges to find those with `shop_id == 5`.  To make use of indices in Gremlin you should use a [vertex query](https://github.com/tinkerpop/blueprints/wiki/Vertex-Query).  So, rewriting your code a bit (to also use [key indices](https://github.com/tinkerpop/blueprints/wiki/Graph-Indices)) would be like:

```
g.V('myIndex',5).outE('HAS_PRODUCT').has('shop_id',5).inV
```

With Blueprints implementations that support vertex-centric indices, the use of `has` will utilize that index automatically.  Unfortunately, Neo4j is not one of those databases yet.  Blueprints implementations that do implement it, include Titan (see [Vertex-centric indices](https://github.com/thinkaurelius/titan/wiki/Vertex-Centric-Indices)) and OrientDB (as part of the yet unreleased Blueprints 2.4.0...I believe they will have a partial implementation in that release) in that case.

Comment: I'm going to be slightly off topic here but is there any sort of ETA on the Neo4j Blueprints implementation supporting vertex-centric indices? Even if not a clear date, just knowledge of it being considered? Thanks

Comment: It really isn't a question of the Blueprints release timeline. I don't think Neo4j has any features currently available that can take  advantage of the vertex query API that Blueprints exposes.  Blueprints implementations that can't take advantage of Vertex Query natively, get "simple" support of the feature because they defer to a default in-memory processor (https://github.com/tinkerpop/blueprints/blob/master/blueprints-core/src/main/java/com/tinkerpop/blueprints/util/DefaultVertexQuery.java), which ends up iterating all results.

Comment: @stephen Thanks for your answer! I was actually looking at this on this page: [link](https://github.com/tinkerpop/gremlin/wiki/Gremlin-Groovy-Path-Optimizations) and couldn't reproduce the querying time gain using the has method. This should motivate a migration toward Titan.

Comment: Neo4j is grouping edges by label and direction starting with release 2.1: http://java.dzone.com/articles/neo4j-210-milestone-1-release